# Setting Uploadfield to overwrite in Silverstripe 4

Tags: php, file-upload, upload, silverstripe, silverstripe-4

In version 3 of Silverstripe, you could set Upload files to overwrite files in your config:

```
# replace files instead of versioning
Upload:
  replaceFile: true
# show an overwrite warning
UploadField:
  defaultConfig:
    overwriteWarning: true
```

I'm hoping to achieve the same thing in SS4 but am unable to find the solution. From what I can glean from the documentation, I need to set `AssetStore::CONFLICT_OVERWRITE` to true, but I'm not sure where to do this.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

`AssetStore::CONFLICT_OVERWRITE` is a constant, so you cannot overwrite it.

But in `UploadField::__construct()` I see:

```
// When creating new files, rename on conflict
$this->getUpload()->setReplaceFile(false);
```

So theoretically you should be able to do something like:

```
$uploadField = UploadField::create(...);
$uploadField->getUpload()->setReplaceFile(true);
```

to overwrite the file.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I'm attempting this with the linked code with no luck, even after running dev/build: https://gist.github.com/mister-cairns/352ff0184921f8940105b6f623d95326